# sphere eversion

Tags: geometry, spheres

I think that you can turn out a sphere inside out just like if there was a hole on it even if you do not make a hole because the sphere can go through itself. Is it correct? Are there some errors? If yes, could you please tell me the error? Or, is there a website that lets me try the sphere eversion?

EDIT: I have watched the video already.

Comment: See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6g3ZcmjJ7k)

Comment: You recieved two answers to your previous question, any reason you didn't accept one of them?

Comment: @5xum I accepted it now. It was hard to decide.